# URI-Scheme to start a call in Cisco Mobile from Safari

Tags: uri, mobile-safari, cisco

I'm developing a web phone book for my company. At the end you can choose a link in the safari browser, and that should start the Cisco Mobile Client and start the call.

The problem is, that the iPad does not start the Cisco Mobile Client by its self. When you use a URI-Scheme like:

`<a href="facetime://4444444444">number</a>`

and click the link, the iPad starts Facetime and calls the number which was given in the link.

Now my question is, is there any URI-Scheme for the Cisco Mobile App for the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. The uri scheme is called 'ciscotel':

```
<a href="ciscotel://4444444444">number</a>
```

This works fine.

If you're looking for other uri schemes, [Zwapp](http://schemes.staging.zwapp.com/) provides a database for different apps.